# Database NULL Value

Tags: ado.net

I have found in my codebase lots of places has been coded as

```
 dr["FIRST_ITEM"].Trim()
```

Now the problem is that if `FIRST_ITEM` column is a allow null values there is chance to encounter Null pointer Exception. I know, I can change the code to

```
Convert.ToString(dr["FIRST_ITEM"]).Trim()
```

in order to fix the problem. But then I have to do this in 1000 lines of code. Can I have solution, by which I can fix the problem with least effort?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up writing a quick method like this:

```
  private static string GetS(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null || obj == DBNull.Value)
                return "";

            return obj.ToString();

        }
```

Example:

```
MyObject.LastName = GetS(dr["LastName"]));
```

Someday I'll have time to go back and write an extention to the DataRow or to write a generic converter.  But for now this works and I have one for dates and bool data types.